# SVG animations and IE (and snap.svg). Animating a paths stroke-dashoffset

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, snap.svg

I have an SVG and I am trying to animate the stroke-dashoffset attribute. Originally I wrote code that did it which worked in internet explorer but then I realised it only worked when you went to the page naturally, from a link within the website i am building but when you refresh the page internet explorer decides it doesnt like it and it doesnt work anymore.

I then read online that the snap.svg library is supposed to be IE friendly so I tried implementing it...turns out I can achieve what I had done before with one line of code using snap.svg...i was achieving it in about 50 lines before haha...although didnt have to include snap.svg so im still not sure which is better...anyway...that line of code is:

```
snapPath.animate({'stroke-dashoffset':stopOffset}, 1000);
```

snapPath is defiend as:

```
var snapMap = Snap('#map'),
    snapPath = snapMap.select('#route_1_overlay');
```

and the stopOffset variable is just a number.

I guess my question is why does it work only when I go to the page through another link on my site and then stop working when I refresh? Is it something to do with the headers in IE? (which makes absolutely no sense to me but is the only thing i can think of which might be different?)

At this point i am willing to just make the stroke-dashoffset just jump to the value I give it instead of animating it but I have also tried that with limited success so I am open to suggestions to be able to achieve this in IE as well.

All this being said if anyone has the answer to making it animate in IE I am all ears!

I am only really concerned with IE10+ and Edge.

Cheers!

Comment: Hard to know without seeing an example or how you've used it. Is it possible IE is caching it somehow or something ?

Comment: Yeah i know what you mean but the thing is theres the whole svg that im using as code plus im integrating it with a slick js carousel...theres a lot of code to replicate basically...ill see if i can get the time to make a slimmed down js fiddle...

Comment: Just thinking, if you can detect some event that's happening when the carousel switches, could you reset the stroke-dashoffset to default on that event.